# Usage of RX interface in LTE and QCI

Tags: lte, qos

I'm currently developing an VOIP application application for LTE and looking to establish communication with the PCRF through the RX interface. My goal is to understand what specific information I need to include in the requests via the RX interface to enable the LTE core to apply QoS rules effectively to my traffic.

I assume that my server needs to provide the PCRF with information that allows for the application of QoS rules to specific packets, such as source/destination IP addresses and ports for both signaling and media streams. However, I'm seeking clarity on how the LTE network applies these rules to individual RTP packets based on the information provided by the PCRF via the RX interface.

Am I on the right track with this logic, or am I completely wrong?

Then there is the concept of QCI. From what I understand QCI is negotiated between UE and LTE network and present in headers in the Evolved Packet System (EPS) of LTE. Is this right?

Is this completely separate from the RX interface and VOIP server's role?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.